# Send value to jquery load

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I have problem when I send a value to the url with jQuery load function

```
function close_session(ruta)
{
jQuery("#lcload").load(ruta + "/mod_register/test.php?action=close_session").show(3000);
}


<a href="#" onclick="close_session('modules')"></a>
```

I call this function from link onclick, the problem is with "ruta", if I writte the value of "ruta" in the script I don't have problem and the url is loaded correctly, the problem is when I want to send the value of "ruta", when I click the link the script doesn't load the content. So, I can't find the problem. I don´t know if I'm writing something wrong. I appreciate any help

Best Regards

Comment: I can't understand your english very well so here it goes in Spanish:
Creo que el problema no lo tienes pasando el valor de ruta, si no con la funcion de jQuery.
Prueba a poner console.log(ruta) dentro de close_session y veras como el valor de ruta si llega.

Comment: I think it works... http://jsfiddle.net/2ejkggph/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with "/" before modules:

```
<a href="#" onclick="close_session('/modules')"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried passing in a second argument as an object instead of url params?

```
jQuery("#lcload").load(""+ruta+"/mod_register/test.php", { action: "close_session"} ).show(3000)
```

Comment: If i don´t pass the value and writte for example modulos/mod_register , etc , works fine , but if i try do the same i put until , no works , and i don´t understand why ........